# position element as if it is the first

Tags: html, css

My situation is something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <p id="first">...</p>
  <p id="second">...</p>
</div>
```

I want `second` to come before first as if it was in the HTML first. If possible, this should be without changing the style of `container` or `first` so as not to impact other layouts. The use case is that the second paragraph is from a plugin, so no control over the other elements.

UPDATE: forgot to mention, I can't use Javascript either.

Comment: You can use prepend() function.

Comment: You could position the second element relativly to the first using `positon:relative` in css or use a Javascript function to move the element in the Document Object Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test with flexbox?

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

#first {
  order:2;
  
}

#second {
    order:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `#container` is a flexbox, you can move `#second` to the first position using `order: -1`.

```css
#container
{
display: flex;
}

#second
{
order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="first">first</p>
  <p id="second">second</p>
</div>
```

If not, you can move the element to the top of the container using `position`, but this will not actually reorder the elements, and you would most likely have to style the container or the other elements to prevent `#second` from rendering on top of another element. If `#container` has `position: relative`, this helps you out a little since you can move the element directly to the top with `top: 0` and `position: absolute` instead of having to use a negative fixed `top` value and `position: relative`, but without knowing exactly what styles are applied to `#container`, we can't know for sure.

Since you can't style `#container` nor any of its children, your options are very limited.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) can help you here.

Depending on if you want a column or row layout you can set the `flex-direction` property on the `.container` element.

You can assign it a value of `row-reverse` or `column-reverse`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <span class="item">Example 1</span>
      <span class="item">Example 2</span>
      <span class="item">Example 3</span>
      <span class="item">Example 4</span>
      <span class="item">Example 5</span>
    </div>
```

depending on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

```
#first { order: 2;}
#second {order: 1;}
```

use above code on your style sheet

or

```
<div id="container">
<p id="first" style='order:2'>...</p>
<p id="second" style='order:1'>...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `order` only applies to _"Flex items, grid items, and absolutely-positioned flex and grid container children"_ (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order#formal_definition) - we don't know if any of that is actually the case here, and we don't know if either of those could be added or not, with OP's requirement to keep the current layout.